# Вопрос по поводу структуры приложения на react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

А кто бы мог подтвердить или опровергнуть? Вот есть create-react-app, после установки мы получаем стандартный набор файлов, среди которых есть App.js. И вот у меня сложилось впечатление, что, работая с файлом App.js, мы должны вкладывать все наши компоненты приложения внутрь дива с классом App, что-то вроде этого:

```
<div className="App">
    <Header />
    <Main />
    <Footer />
</div>
```

И если мы создадим другие дивы, функции вне дива с классом App, то будет ошибкой. Допустим, такая структура будет ошибочной или нет?

```
<div className="Header">
    <Header />
</div>
<div className="App">
    <Main />
    <Footer />
</div>
```

В документации Реакта где-нибудь написано про правила, связанные с div с классом App? Я понимаю, что дело не в названии App, можно придумать другое, но суть в том, что у нас главный файл с расширением .js со строгой структурой и правилами, где мы складываем наши компоненты, и который рендерится в index.js.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том что в App.js так же является компонентом, а у каждого компонента должен быть один div внутри которого можешь уже писать свой код, нет никакой разницы в классе может быть любой div и даже просто <>...</>